# Techn. Übersetzung: to serve a document

Tags: translation, english-to-german, technical-terminology, idiomaticity, software

Ich übersetze momentan eine kleine Dokumentation für ein Softwareprojekt zur Entwicklung von Webanwendungen. An einigen Stellen heißt es in Bezug auf Webserver: "to serve a document", womit die übertragene Webseite gemeint ist.

Dienen bzw. servieren wäre im übertragenen Sinne logisch, jedoch klingt es nicht idiomatisch. Kennt jemand eine passendere Übersetzung, um bei einer Anfrage bzw. dem Aufrufen der Webseite sich eine Datei/Homepage "servieren" zu lassen?

Comment: Hast du zufällig einen kompletten Satz damit? Das würde mir helfen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ein Webserver kann eine Datei **bereitstellen** oder **ausliefern**.

Comment: Danke für das schnelle Feedback. Die Vorschläge passen und liefern auch gleich ein Paar Synonyme.

Answer (score 3):

Eine Seite *ausliefern*, oder (wenn es weniger technisch sein soll) vielleicht *anzeigen*.

Comment: Bei *anzeigen* würde ich die Stirne runzeln - Browser zeigen was an, nicht Webserver. Aber ich bin auch ein Techie...